# Favicon on Safari URL bar

Tags: javascript, html, safari, favicon

I wanted to add favicon for my website, it works both on Chrome and FF but wouldn't on Safari (I have version 7 installed on my macbook). I tried different tricks mentioned on forums and had no luck. For example removing the following:

1. Library/Caches/com.apple.WebKit.PluginProcess/Cache.db
2. WebpageIcons.db
3. Safari Cache/reset

My favicon is 32x32 and following is the code I use.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/favicon.ico"/>
```

Any ideas, how can i get it working?

Comment: what colour depth is the icon?

Answer (score 1):

Save your favicon as an 8bit (jpg is 8-bit, but png is better and you can save for web as 8-bit, it doesn't need to be .ico) image and make sure to clear your cache. 
On upload, it should show in all browsers.

Comment: Do you have photoshop? Even paint would save it as a jpg

Comment: Or you could do it online

Comment: thanks, saving as jpg is fine but not sure how to specify 8-bit thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a problem with your browser, put the `favicon.ico` in the index of your site, that is in `/public_html/` folder and try clearing cache after.

    **`/public_html/`** folder is the **default** place that browser look for **favicon** in.
Also you can set the fave icon you want by using `< link >` tag, as you did.
Try setting address without `<%=request.getContextPath()%>`just the path for the file

e.g. `href="http://MyWebSite.com/favicon.ico"`

    Sometimes it needs up to ~24h more or less to be updated.


If none of that worked try opening your site on another computer.
**Online Favicon Generators:

1.[Favicon & App Icon Generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/)

2.[Favicon Generator and Gallery](http://www.favicon.co.uk/)

3.[favicon.ico Generator](http://www.favicon.cc/)

4.[X-Icon Editor](http://www.xiconeditor.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

What you need for Safari icon to appear on iphone Hoescreen if it's what you're looking for is this :

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/a/img/icons/apple-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/a/img/icons/apple-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/a/img/icons/apple-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/a/img/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png" />
```

You don't need it to be a ico image for that purpose.
You don't need it to be at the root of your webserver for that purpose.

I tested that.